Difference vs Differential (nouns - data analysis context)
Regarding the tweet: https://twitter.com/TheAthleticFC/status/1850616203498410243,

Manchester United have the biggest negative differential between expected goals and goals scored in the Premier League this season (8 goals from 14.6 xG).

Is it incorrect to use "differential" here instead of "difference." For context, goals scored and expected goals (or xG) are measured differently. In other words, they are distinct entities by definition. Differential, however, is commonly used to compare quantities of metrics/variables that share an identical structure of measurement.

Look it up first please.

It's sports statistics not academic mathematics, you can't expect it to have the same terminology. (Although I've no idea why you think it's wrong to compare the actual and expected value of something.)

There is nothing wrong with comparing the actual and expected value of something. However, if the two values are measured differently then "difference" is usually the go-to. I asked this question because this instance is an isolated case, not a universal representative.
